# How to retrun all documents to the list in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to return my all documents in firestore my document in Identifier based on name but when I do my function its return to me With the same number I have documents but the name its different instance of DocumentSnapshot but I need to return same names I have. How can I do this? Below is the code I am using

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return StreamBuilder < QuerySnapshot > (
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Institute")
                .document(widget.id).collection("Ravs").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print('list of docment:${snapshot.data.documents.toList()}');
            };
            return CircularProgressIndicator();

        }

    );
}
```

Comment: Can you re-structure your question to make it clearer? I did not understood what is the problem you are facing and what is the outcome that you expect with this.

Comment: i need to return all my documents i have in my subcollocation   in my code its return the same number but the deterrent name its return  all names like instance of DocumentSnapshot ...but  I want return the same name i have on my database

Comment: Try adding `.data()` after `.snapshots()`, this will return a map of the values inside of your snapshot, ie. your actual document, not the snapshot instance itself, try it out and let me know if it works and it is what you expected.

Comment: Has the solution provided above fixed what you were facing? If so let me know so I can add it to an official answer for you to accept so that the community knows that you have been sufficiently helped.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in my response  I just tiring your code tody thankyou it's working good

Comment: Great, I have posted it as an official answer for you to accept/upvote it so that the community can see that your inquiry is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Instance of DocumentSnapshot` log is saying that you are interacting with the Snapshot object itself. which is what your code is indeed doing.

To get access to the data inside the Snapshot you have to add the `.data()` call next to your Snapshot, so your `stream` should look like this:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Institute").document(widget.id)
                 .collection("Ravs").snapshots().data()
```